# Recursive number function returns unexpected values

Tags: c, string, recursion, int

After searching extensively for a function that would convert integers into visually equivalent strings and finding nothing, I decided to write my own.

The function "ascii" takes three arguments: the integer to be converted, the string to hold the converted integer, and a counter that is meant to be left at 0.

```
void ascii(int c, char str[], int k) {
    if (c <= 9) {
        str[k] = c + '0';
    }

    else if (c >= 10) {
        str[k] = c / 10 + '0';
        ascii(c % 10, str, k + 1);
    }
}
```

Testing this function with a single-digit number turns up nothing unexpected, but on bigger numbers, things start to get messy. 76 becomes "761", 765 becomes "|51", and 7658 becomes "-81". The more digits the number is comprised of, the less sense I can make out of the resulting string. What gives?

Comment: Protip: use `sprintf` with the `%d` specifier (even better, `snprintf` in C99 or if your compiler supports it).

Comment: Why can't you use sprintf?

Comment: Not an answer but replacing `+ 48` with `+'0'` would result in more readable code

Comment: ... and also more portable (at least in theory).

Comment: How do you output? do you add a `\0` to the end?

Comment: In your extensive search, didn't you find `sprintf`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I belive here's the problem:

```
else if (c >= 10) {
    str[k] = c % 10 + 48;
    ascii(c / 10, str, k + 1);
}
```

The arithmetic operations were inverted. The resulting array must be inverted afterwards (from a different function, that calls the function in the question as a helper), and it must end in a `'\0'` char.

Alternatively, you could copy the results in the output array in reverse order, but that's assuming you know beforehand the number of digits.

Comment: ... still, this would output the digits in reverse order.

Comment: I think his output is in the reverse order

Comment: Both of you're right. I added this as a warning at the end, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and meaningful answer! I didn't even notice that the operations were reversed. Pretty stupid of me, haha :)

Answer (score 1):

For the case `c = 123`, you are effectively doing this:

```
    str[k] = 12 + '0';
    ascii(3, str, k + 1);
```

I'm not sure what you intend to happen, but that's probably not what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers pointed out the most important mistake - you swapped the modulo and the division; still, even with the correction, the produced string will be inverted, since with the modulo you get quickly the least significant digit, that should go to the right, but you put it to the left because at the beginning is unknown the final length of the string.

You can either invert this string, find the number of digits using a logarithm or use an alternative recursive approach:

```
void ascii(int c, char str[])
{
    if(c<0)
    {
        *(str++)='-';
        c=-c;
    }
    *(ascii_helper(c, str))='\0';
}

char * ascii_helper(int c, char str[])
{
    if (c > 9)
        str=ascii_helper(c/10, str);
    *str = c%10 + '0';
    return str+1;
}
```

This works by deferring the actual write of the digits until their positions are known. The recursion goes on until the most significant digit has been found, then each call returns to its caller the position of the next character, which is used to correctly position of each digit. Notice that this function can't be tail-optimized like the original one, so it's less space-efficient (although this is mostly indifferent since `int`s can't usually hold more than 20 digits anyway).

Answer (score 0):

- firstly you swapped the modulo and divide,that is why you are getting those unexpected answers.
- moreover this gives the reverse answer taht you are expecting.so revese the number and then try too solve it.

  ```
  void ascii(int c, char str[], int k) {
  /*first let us reverse the string
  because recursive solution will be reverse of our expected solution*/
  int r=0,i;
  for(i=c;i>0;i=i/10)
  r=r*10+i%10;

  if (r <= 9) {
      str[k] = r + '0';

  }
  else if (r >= 10) {
       ascii(r / 10, str, k+1 );
       str[k] = r%10 + '0';
  }
  return;
  }
  ```